# ask pip to use ssh instead of https when doing pip freeze for local module's source repo url

Tags: python, pip, gitlab

I am using local packages in my project. My code is version controlled on GitLab.

When I do pip freeze on my project, I get below output in my requirements.txt file:

```
-e git+https://gitlab.com/someuser/someproject.git@1234567890#egg=commonlogger&subdirectory=svcs/common/commonlogger
```

How do I ask `pip` to not use `https` and use `ssh` protocol like this:

```
 -e git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/someuser/someproject.git@1234567890#egg=commonlogger&subdirectory=svcs/common/commonlogger
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip` cannot do it so you need to use an external tool. For example with `sed`:

```
pip freeze | sed "s!git+https://!git+ssh://!" >requirements.txt
```

Comment: just had to replace double quotes with single quotes. thank you for the answer.